# Javascript: setTimeout() is not removing the class

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to apply a class just for 3 seconds, why is the class not being removed.

```js
var x = 0;
var notes = ['a','b','c'];
while (x < notes.length) {
  document.getElementById(notes[x]).classList.add('active');
  x++;
}
function RemoveClass() {
  var x = 0;
  while (x < notes.length) {
    document.getElementById(notes[x]).classList.remove("active");
    x++;
  }
  
}
window.setTimeout(RemoveClass, 3000);
```

```css
.active{color:blue}
```

```html
<div id="a">First</div>
<div id="b">Second</div>
<div id="c">Third</div>
```

Comment: Please add the html block along with the JS code.

Comment: A while loop is not a great choice here; you are setting a new timeout every loop.

Comment: Edited, check if works.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roy! this was really helpful :D